# "std::format"ing std::chrono seconds without fractional digits

Tags: c++, stl, formatting, c++20, c++-chrono

What is the *correct* way to format seconds in c++20 (using std::format) without also showing fractional digits?

---

This code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main()
    {
        std::cout << std::format("{:%H:%M:%S}",  std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::format("{:%H:%M:%OS}", std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << std::endl;
    }
```

Produces this output (via trunk GCC (14.0.0 20230425)):

```
00:18:07.087240403
00:18:07.087622600
```

---

I just want the integer part (eg `00:18:07` without the trailing `.087240403`).
It's very easy to remove the remainder from the resulting string after the fact (or manually extract the seconds and print them separately), but I'd be very surprised if that was the intended solution.

---

The formatting codes are described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter#Format_specification). AFAICT there is no `%S` variant that explicitly rounds or truncates the seconds to the nearest integer.

The explanation (from the link above) for %S (and %OS below) is:

> Writes the second as a decimal number. If the number of seconds is less than 10, the result is prefixed with 0.

> If the precision of the input cannot be exactly represented with seconds, then the format is a decimal floating-point number with a fixed format and a precision matching that of the precision of the input (or to a microseconds precision if the conversion to floating-point decimal seconds cannot be made within 18 fractional digits). The character for the decimal point is localized according to the locale.

> The modified command %OS writes the locale's alternative representation.

---

GCC/glibc is functioning correctly here, right? (It seems to fit the explanation above).

If so, what's the *intended* way to achieve this?

1. Do I use a different format string?
2. Do I use a different clock?
3. Do I manually round the value first? (It still shows the fractional part if rounded).
4. Or do I really have to manually strip the fractional part or manually extract the seconds.

(*If* this isn't *trivially* achievable, could this be considered potentially undesirable behavior, perhaps a STL defect?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`time_point_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_point_cast) to convert its duration to `seconds` and then format it:

```
auto now = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(
             std::chrono::system_clock::now()
           );
std::cout << std::format("{:%H:%M:%S}", now) << std::endl;
```

Comment: +1. Additional info: `floor<seconds>` also works, and could be considered preferred as it will round down both before and after the epoch.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do you think, however, that there _should_ be a format code for discrete/integer seconds? Because this solution still seems inelegant.

Comment: [For floating point based type you can specify a precision.](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.format#1.sentence-4)  For integral based types getting the full precision of the argument (when possible) has led to the fewest complaints.  What is typical is that the desired working precision is chosen earlier than the point of format, and then no longer worried about.  Things just work. Additionally, use of _local_ using directives or declarations goes a long way towards making the code more concise and readable:  `cout << format(":%T}", floor<seconds>(now)) << '\n';`

Comment: I'm not suggesting removing current functionality. But there's plenty of letters left, and `cout << format("{:%K}", now) ....` (where, say, K = integer seconds) seems cleaner than IMHO inconsistently requiring an explicit `floor<seconds>` cast for %S when it's not needed for %M or %H.

Comment: Actually, lowercase `s` is still unused.

Comment: [How to submit a proposal to change the C++ standard](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal).